# Flutter "Exception caught by image resource service... Unable to load asset: appleandbook.png"

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I made a mistake learning the image widget.I browsed dozens of forums and watched videos but it never improved, I will be glad if you help.
The scripts I wrote are as follows:
main.dart

return Center(
child: MaterialApp(
title: 'Flutter Learning',
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
theme: ThemeData().copyWith(
cardTheme: CardTheme(
shape: StadiumBorder(),
),
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
centerTitle: true,

```
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        )),
        home: ImageWidgetLearn(),
      ),
    );
```

image_learn.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class ImageWidgetLearn extends StatelessWidget {
  String appBarTitle = "Image Learn";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appBarTitle),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black45,
              height: 0.5,
            ),
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1.0),
          )),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("selam aleyküm"),
          Image.asset('assets/images/appleandbook.png')
        ],
      ),    
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: flutterfulllearn
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.5 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  # uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - assets\images\appleandbook.png

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

and **error message**
[error message like this][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5ySj.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pubspec.yaml file change the assets path  like this

```
assets/images/appleandbook.png
```

Change the backslash `\`  by  slash `/`

Comment: Thanks and fun coding (:

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have messed with slashes. Instead of `/` you should use `\`. So that the code in your yaml file should look like next

```
  assets:
    - assets\images\appleandbook.png
```

After that, dont forget to recompile your app so that resources are included

Comment: it worked for me, enjoyable coding bro :)